# How to query database prior to a select action?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a user profile form that allows a user to change their address, city, state, zip.

The code below will show/hide the list of states/provinces if the country is not US or CA.

However, if the user already has this information stored in the database, I'm unable to get the state/province to load the list of locations and to select the one previously stored in the database. It only works when I select a different country which hides the state/province, then select US. When I do this, then the state stored in the database also becomes selected.

I'm not very good with Javascript, and I believe the issue is I'm only calling the ajax function when the country is selected. If the country is already selected because the user previously filled in the form, then the ajax call does not happen. How can I call it whether the page loads or the select action on the country happens?

**HTML**

profile.php

```
<div class="mb-3">
  <label class="form-label mb-0 fw-bold" for="country"><small>Country/Region</small></label>
  <select class="form-select" id="country" name="country">
    <option value=""></option>
    <?php include("/get_countries.php"); ?>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="mb-3" id="stateShowHide" <?php if ($stateShowHide == "hide") { print("<style=\"display:none;\">"); } ?>>
  <label class="form-label mb-0 fw-bold" for="state"><small>State/Province</small></label>
  <select class="form-select" id="state" name="state">
  </select>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#country").on('change', function() {
            var selectedCountry = $("#country option:selected").val();

            if ( this.value == "CA" || this.value == "US") {
                        
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "https://www.example.com/get_states.php?state=<?php print($state); ?>",
                    data: { country : selectedCountry }
                }).done(function(data) {
                    $("#state").html(data);
                });

                $("#stateShowHide").show();

            } else {
                $("#stateShowHide").hide();
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

**PHP**

get_states.php

```
if (isset($_GET["state"])) {
    $state = check_input($_GET["state"]);
}

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    print("<option value=\"" . $row["state"] . "\"");
    if ($state == $row["state"]) {
        print("selected");
    }
    print(">" . $row["state"] . "</option>\n");
}
```

Screenshots

https://imgur.com/a/yhmKqX1

Comment: So where do you load the states from the database? `$row['state']` you dont query that database or fetch a row??

Comment: Take a deep breath, think about the logic flow of what you are trying to do and rewrite this code, almost none of it make any sense

Comment: You can either trigger the change handler for the first select when the page loads - https://api.jquery.com/trigger/ Or you could include your `get_states.php` inside that second select on the server side already; then you just need to find a way to pass it the value already stored on the user profile. (You could _set_ `$_GET["state"]` before, if that doesn't mess with the rest of your script logic, or you use a different variable, and then rewrite the code to see if that is set first, and if not use the GET parameter as "second choice".)

Comment: If you can, do not add the image as a link. Someday the link will stop working and your question, however best it may be, will become useless. Add graphics as image or code as formatted text.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make be this could help you.

```
<script>
    function onCountryChange(){
        var selectedCountry = $("#country option:selected").val();
        
        if (selectedCountry == "CA" || selectedCountry == "US") {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "https://www.example.com/get_states.php?state=<?php print($state); ?>",
                data: { country : selectedCountry }
            }).done(function(data) {
                $("#state").html(data);
            });

            $("#stateShowHide").show();

        } else {
            $("#stateShowHide").hide();
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#country").on('change', onCountryChange);    
    });

</script>

<?php
if (isset($_GET["state"])) {
    $state = check_input($_GET["state"]);
}

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    print("<option value=\"" . $row["state"] . "\"");
    if ($state == $row["state"]) {
        print("selected");
    }
    print(">" . $row["state"] . "</option>\n");
}

echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
     'onCountryChange();',
     '</script>'
;
?>
```

After completing your forEach just call onCountryChange()

Comment: This did not work for me. I just see a blank select drop down for states still.

Comment: share code when the country is previously selected by user. Where you mark country as selected.

Comment: Is your get_countries.php code same as get_states()? How do you mark the country as already selected? good if you share get_countries.php code

Comment: Yes, it's similar. It appears as <option value="US" selected>United States</option>

Comment: That's the problem. We are never going to know when the country list is rendered and a particular country is marked as selected. Instead of generating Html on the server-side. You need to get the country list array with the selected country from the server. Then completing getCountry ajax call we can get states list.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. The country is produced server-side.

Comment: The post above shows it's a separate PHP file querying the database and bringing the results to the page from the server end. Only the states are produced via AJAX call.

Comment: You are producing a country list at the server-side that's the problem. you are not able to detect when the country list is loaded at the client side, so we are unable to get the state for that country.

Comment: Well I'm an idiot. I had the JS code above the PHP code for country/state, so it never saw what was selected. Your code does work! THANK YOUUUUU